# Calculate wages according to different pay rate format

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, logic, strtotime

I am currently working on one project and come across a challenge that I am unable to resolve so far. I have tried long and hard and eventually putting my scenarios here as I can get some useful tips. Also, bear with me as I am going to give a whole details of the problem.

So, I have a project that contains the module which calculates the wages of their employees based on their shift timings (time is 24 hour format). Now, the pay rate is different according to the timings such as in week days (Monday to Friday) the pay rate is divided in two sections: `Week Day` and `Week Night.` Moreover, the `weekend` (Saturday & Sunday) pay rate is also different than normal days. Finally, there are `public holidays` and they also have different pay rates than rest of the events. Following table shows the summary of the pay rates:

```
------------------------------------------
|Event         | Shift Times              |
------------------------------------------
|Week Day      | 0600-1800                |
------------------------------------------
|Week Night    | 1800-0600                |
------------------------------------------
|Weekend       | All day weekend rate     |
-------------------------------------------
|Public holiday|All day public holiday rate|
-------------------------------------------+
```

Now, this looks really simple if you have to assign pay rates only for that particular day such as the shift is on public holiday then assign public holiday rates but the problem is this is not a case in my project.

**How it works**

Now, the shift is usually 12 hour long and can fall between two different pay rates such as one employee starts at `0900` and finishes `2100` on `Monday`. So, the calculations of hours would be like 9 hours on `week day` pay rate and 3 hours on `week night` pay rate. Similarly, the employee can do shift in a way that it can fall in  three different pay rates like : shift starts at `2200` Sunday night and finishes at `0900` on the `Monday` morning. Therefore, the pay rate hours would be like 2 hours on `weekend` rate as the shift starts on Sunday night and and weekend end after 2 hours. So, from `0000` to `0600` (6 hours )the  pay rate would be based on `week night` rate and rest of the hours comes under week day.

Now the good news is that I am able to do this up until now. Everything works perfect. Although I have put so many conditions inside it which i believe is not a good practice but for time being i want to make it run. The problem arise when `Public Holiday` happens. Now the public holiday is the most difficult part as it can come on any day (week day and weekends) and have to recheck in every condition and have to do the additions and subtractions of hours which is too complicated and not working. I am able to do the part if the whole shift falls on public holiday. However, when it falls more than one pay rate category then it becomes tough for me to solve the issue. I would not share the public holiday one code as the code is too complicated and you might get confused.However, I am going to share  the code where other pay rate formats are working fine.

**Note**
I would advice you to not get any ideas from my code as i want your suggestions and you might run out of ideas if you look at my code.

```
function getHoursBreakDown($time1, $time2){

    $hoursForShift = array(
        "weekday" => 0,
        "weeknight" => 0,
        "saturday" => 0,
        "sunday" => 0,
        "public" => 0
    );

    $t1 = strtotime($time1);
    $t2 = strtotime($time2);

    $t1_Day = (int) date("N", $t1);
    $t2_Day = (int) date("N", $t2);

    $t1_Hour = (int) date("G", $t1);
    $t2_Hour = (int) date("G", $t2);

    $t1_Date = (int) date("j", $t1);
    $t2_Date = (int) date("j", $t2);

    $t1_Month = (int) date("n", $t1);
    $t2_Month = (int) date("n", $t2);

    $t1_Minutes = round(date("i", $t1) / 60, 2); // to substitute, extra
    $t2_Minutes = round(date("i", $t2) / 60, 2); // to add, lost

    // Working days
    if ($t1_Day<6) {


        if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;

        for($i = $t1_Hour; $i< $t2_Hour; $i++){


            if (($i>= 6 && $i < 18) || ($t2_Day < 6 && $i >= 30) ) {
                $hoursForShift['weekday']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day < 6 || $i < 24) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day == 6) {
                $hoursForShift['saturday']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day == 7) {
                $hoursForShift['sunday']++;
            }
        }

        $t2_Hour = ($t2_Hour > 23) ? $t2_Hour - 24: $t2_Hour;

        // Deducting extra minutes from sign in time
        if      ($t1_Hour >= 6 && $t1_Hour < 18) $hoursForShift['weekday']   -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Hour  < 6 || $t1_Hour >= 18) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] -= $t1_Minutes;

        // Adding lost minutes to sign out
        if      ($t2_Day < 6 && ($t2_Hour >= 6 && $t2_Hour < 18)){  $hoursForShift['weekday']   += $t2_Minutes; }
        else if ($t2_Day < 6 && ($t2_Hour  < 6 || $t2_Hour >= 18))  $hoursForShift['weeknight'] += $t2_Minutes;

        // Adding lost minutes to sign out if, sign out on weekend
        if      ($t2_Day == 6) $hoursForShift['saturday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday'] += $t2_Minutes;

    } else {
        //Weekends

        if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;

        for($i = $t1_Hour; $i< $t2_Hour; $i++){

            if ($t2_Day == 1 && ($i%24) < 12) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']++;

            } else if ($t1_Day == 6 && $i < 24) {
                $hoursForShift['saturday']++;

            } else if ($t1_Day == 7 || ($t1_Day == 6 && $i >= 24)) {
                $hoursForShift['sunday']++;
            }
        }

        if ($t2_Day == 1) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        if ($t2_Day == 6) $hoursForShift['saturday'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday'] -= $t1_Minutes;

        if ($t2_Day == 1) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 6) $hoursForShift['saturday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday']   += $t2_Minutes;
    }
}
```

Good thing is that nothing is coming out from database. This problem is based on totally mind calculations and techniques and invloves pure PHP.

Please any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: by pay rate you mean **hourly** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huff !! After working long and hard and pulling my hairs all day eventually I am able to figure out the solution of the problem. Following function is the all the answer of the question I was looking for.

```
   function getHoursBreakDown($time1, $time2){

    $hoursForShift = array(
        "weekday" => 0,
        "weeknight" => 0,
        "saturday" => 0,
        "sunday" => 0,
        "public" => 0
    );

    $t1 = strtotime($time1);
    $t2 = strtotime($time2);

    $t1_Day = (int) date("N", $t1);
    $t2_Day = (int) date("N", $t2);

    $t1_Hour = (int) date("G", $t1);
    $t2_Hour = (int) date("G", $t2);

    $t1_Date = (int) date("j", $t1);
    $t2_Date = (int) date("j", $t2);

    $t1_Month = (int) date("n", $t1);
    $t2_Month = (int) date("n", $t2);

    $t1_Year = (int) date("Y", $t1);
    $t2_Year = (int) date("Y", $t2);

    $t1_Minutes = round(date("i", $t1) / 60, 2); // to substitute, extra
    $t2_Minutes = round(date("i", $t2) / 60, 2); // to add, lost

    $start=explode(' ', $time1);
    $finish=explode(' ', $time2);

       $publicHolidays = array(
        "2014-01-01",
        "2014-01-27",
        "2014-04-18",
        "2014-04-19",
        "2014-04-21",
        "2014-04-25",
        "2014-06-09",
        "2014-08-17",
        "2014-10-06",
        "2014-11-14",
        "2014-12-25",
        "2014-12-26"

    );


    // Working days
    if ($t1_Day<6 ) {

        if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;

        for($i = $t1_Hour; $i< $t2_Hour; $i++){


            if (($i>= 6 && $i < 18) || ($t2_Day < 6 && $i >= 30 && $i< 42) ) {
                $hoursForShift['weekday']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day < 6 || $i < 24) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day == 6) {
                $hoursForShift['saturday']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day == 7) {
                $hoursForShift['sunday']++;
            }
        }

        $t2_Hour = ($t2_Hour > 23) ? $t2_Hour - 24: $t2_Hour;

        // Deducting extra minutes from sign in time
        if((!in_array($start[0], $publicHolidays)) && (!in_array($finish[0], $publicHolidays))) {
        if      ($t1_Hour >= 6 && $t1_Hour < 18) $hoursForShift['weekday']   -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Hour  < 6 || $t1_Hour >= 18) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] -= $t1_Minutes;

        // Adding lost minutes to sign out
        if      ($t2_Day < 6 && ($t2_Hour >= 6 && $t2_Hour < 18)){  $hoursForShift['weekday']   += $t2_Minutes; }
        else if ($t2_Day < 6 && ($t2_Hour  < 6 || $t2_Hour >= 18))  $hoursForShift['weeknight'] += $t2_Minutes;

        // Adding lost minutes to sign out if, sign out on weekend
        if      ($t2_Day == 6) $hoursForShift['saturday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday'] += $t2_Minutes;
    }

    } else if($t1_Day>=6)  {
        //Weekends

        if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;

        for($i = $t1_Hour; $i< $t2_Hour; $i++){


            if ($t2_Day == 1 &&  $i>=24 && $i<30) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']++;

            }else if ($t2_Day == 1 && $i>29  && $i<42) {
                $hoursForShift['weekday']++;

            }else if ($t1_Day == 6 && $i < 24) {
                $hoursForShift['saturday']++;

            } else if ($t1_Day == 7 || ($t1_Day == 6 && $i >= 24)) {
                $hoursForShift['sunday']++;
            }
        }


        if((!in_array($start[0], $publicHolidays)) && (!in_array($finish[0], $publicHolidays))) {
        $t2_Hour = ($t2_Hour > 23) ? $t2_Hour - 24: $t2_Hour;

        if ($t1_Day == 1 && $t1_Hour>=0 && $t1_Hour<6 ) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day == 1 && $t1_Hour>=6 && $t1_Hour<18 ) $hoursForShift['weekday'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day == 6) $hoursForShift['saturday'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday'] -= $t1_Minutes;

        if ($t2_Day == 1 && $t2_Hour<6 || $t2_Day == 1 && $t2_Hour>=18) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 1 && $t2_Hour>=6 && $t2_Hour < 18) $hoursForShift['weekday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 6 ) $hoursForShift['saturday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday']   += $t2_Minutes;
    }

    }
       // If the start and end date is public holiday
        if((in_array($start[0], $publicHolidays)) && (in_array($finish[0], $publicHolidays)))

        {

            $hoursForShift['public'] = $hoursForShift['weekday'];
            $hoursForShift['weekday'] = 0;

            $hoursForShift['public'] += $hoursForShift['weeknight'];
            $hoursForShift['weeknight'] = 0;

            $hoursForShift['public'] += $hoursForShift['saturday'];
            $hoursForShift['saturday'] = 0;

            $hoursForShift['public'] += $hoursForShift['sunday'];
            $hoursForShift['sunday'] = 0;

            $hoursForShift['public'] -= $t1_Minutes;
            $hoursForShift['public'] += $t2_Minutes;

           //If start date is on public holiday but the end date
        }else if ((in_array($start[0], $publicHolidays)) && (! in_array($finish[0], $publicHolidays))) {


           if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;


           for($i = $t1_Hour; $i<24; $i++){

            if($t1_Day<6){    


            if (($i>=6 && $i <18)) {
                $hoursForShift['weekday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            } else if ($i >=18 && $i <24) {

                $hoursForShift['weeknight']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            }
            else if ($i>0 && $i<=6) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;
             } 
           } else if ($t1_Day == 6) {

                $hoursForShift['saturday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            } else if ($t1_Day == 7) {

                $hoursForShift['sunday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;
            }
        }

         $t2_Hour = ($t2_Hour > 23) ? $t2_Hour - 24: $t2_Hour;

         $hoursForShift['public'] -= $t1_Minutes;


        if ($t2_Day <6 && $t2_Hour>0 && $t2_Hour<6 || $t2_Day <6 && $t2_Hour>=18) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day <6 && $t2_Hour>=6 && $t2_Hour < 18) $hoursForShift['weekday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 6 ) $hoursForShift['saturday'] += $t2_Minutes;
        else if ($t2_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday']   += $t2_Minutes;

        //If the start date is not on a public holiday but end date is.

        }else if ((! in_array($start[0], $publicHolidays)) && (in_array($finish[0], $publicHolidays))) {


           if ($t1_Hour > $t2_Hour) $t2_Hour += 24;


           for($i = 25; $i<= $t2_Hour; $i++){

            if($t2_Day<6){    

            if ( $i>24 && $i <=30 ) {
                $hoursForShift['weeknight']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            } else if ($i >=30 && $i < 42 ) {

                $hoursForShift['weekday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            }

           } else if ($t2_Day == 6) {

                $hoursForShift['saturday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;

            } else if ($t2_Day == 7) {

                $hoursForShift['sunday']--;
                $hoursForShift['public']++;
            }
        }


         $hoursForShift['public'] += $t2_Minutes;


        if ($t1_Day <6 && $t1_Hour>0 && $t1_Hour<6 || $t1_Day <6 && $t1_Hour>=18) $hoursForShift['weeknight'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day <6 && $t1_Hour>=6 && $t1_Hour < 18) $hoursForShift['weekday'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day == 6 ) $hoursForShift['saturday'] -= $t1_Minutes;
        else if ($t1_Day == 7) $hoursForShift['sunday']   -= $t1_Minutes;


        }


     return $hoursForShift;
    }
```

Comment: This does not work if shift is bigger than 24 hours.